# Can't import Interface to another contract. (TypeError)

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

This is a snippet of my main code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import 'IERC20.sol';

contract Kaarya is IERC20 {

   uint public constant _totalSupply = 1000000;

   string public constant symbol = "KRY";
   string public constant name = "Kaarya Token";
   uint8 public constant decimals = 3;


   mapping(address => uint256) balances;
   mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowed;


   constructor() public{
       balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
   }


   function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
       return _totalSupply;
   }


   function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[account];
   }


   function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
       require (
        balances[msg.sender] >= amount
        && amount > 0
    );
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[recipient] += amount;
    Transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
    return true;
    }

   function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
       require(
           allowed[sender][msg.sender] >= amount
           && balances[sender] >= value
           && amount > 0
       );
       balances[sender] -= amount;
       balances[recipient] += amount;
       allowed[sender][msg.sender] -= amount;
       return true;
   }

   function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256) {
       return allowed[owner][spender];
   }

   function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
       allowed[msg.sender][spender] = amount;
       Approval(msg.sender, spender, amount);
       return true;
   }

   event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

   event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
```

}

I get the error: TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract. Contract Kaarya is IERC20 {

This is a snippet of the code for what I'm importing:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
```

I checked other similar questions in StackExchange but still doesn't work. Any help would be great!

Comment: Try without the `as IERC20`.

Comment: @goodvibration without it I get an error 'Undeclared Identifier' for all variables.

Comment: First of all, before everything, please fix up your question. Those two contracts that you've posted - each one of them misses **by the least** one closing curly brace. I have the feeling that it's not the only thing missing there, which could explain the error that you're getting. But without seeing your full code, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: `as IERC20` is a syntax error. The correct syntax is `import {IERC20} from './IERC20.sol';`

Comment: @goodvibration Please, be gentle, we are all here because we want to help others.

Comment: @Ismael: Of course. I wasn't meaning to be un-gentle.

Comment: @goodvibration sorry, my bad. i added the full code. i don't think there's an error with the number of brackets. i guess all of them are already closed.

Comment: @Ismael by changing it to what you said, i get the same 'Undeclared Identifier' all variables.

Comment: @RohitHandique. In the function `balanceOf` you are using `_owner` but such variable was never declared, you probably wanted to use `account` instead. The other issues are similar you are using a variable that is not defined. You should learn a simpler language if you are just starting to program.

Comment: @Ismael my bad. i was using a different erc20 protocol with a different tutorial so the variable names were different and so unidentified. if i do use account instead of _owner, it does work. thank you for helping!

Comment: @Ismael i did what you told me to. all the variables show no error except 1. I've updated the question with the error at the bottom as Edit 1. can you please help me out with it too? also I've updated my main code at the top with the updated names of the variables.

Comment: @RohitHandique. The error is not for `sender` but for `value`.

Comment: @Ismael I'm really embarrassed by posting such a doubt, should have obviously checked it properly. thank you for helping. also had another error where it said: "overriding function is missing override specifier". I wrote "override" after defining every function because of calling it from another different contract and now it works. thanks a lot for calmly listening and helping!